# Arduino https calls work when code is moved from "loop" to separate function. Why?

Tags: arduino, client, esp8266

I made a simple https calling routine, which I use to test wheter or not a certain server replies. It uses ESP8266WiFi and WiFiClientSecure libs. The setup section looks like this (ssid and password defined earlier of course):

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi connected");
    Serial.println("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
```

-So it's a copy-paste from the examples, and it works fine. The rest of the code is also more or less from the examples, except i put in in the loop section since I wanted it to repeat over and over:

```
void loop() {
    if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        connectToWifi();
    }

    WiFiClientSecure client;
    Serial.print("connecting to ");
    Serial.println(host);
    if (!client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
        Serial.println("connection failed");
        return;
    }

    String url = "/Views/Something.aspx";
    Serial.print("requesting URL: ");
    Serial.println(url);

    client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
        "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
        "User-Agent: BuildFailureDetectorESP8266\r\n" +
        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

    int zzz = random(5000) + 500;
    delay(zzz);
}
```

This code would run between five and ten times or so, and then just stop doing anything. Some testing revealed that it would indeed pass the "delay(zzz)" code, but then nothing more happened.

Now here's the thing: I took the "loop" code and moved it into a function, which I call from within the "loop" section. And for no apparent reason, now it runs and runs with no problem.

The only reason I could think of, is if objects that are instanciated within "loop()" aren't properly released, and perhaps because of that I would run out of memory when a horde of WiFiClientSecure objects were left lingering. But that's just a vague guess - and I'd really like to understand what happened!
Getting it to work was satisfying, but unless I get WHY I really haven't learned much! =)

Comment: Maybe try to check memory consumption with `ESP.getFreeHeap()`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that once I am back at that computer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the delay is set in the main loop you are essentially blocking all the background utility functions, things to do with managing the TCP/IP stack etc.

The reason that it works 5-10 times is because of the random size of the delay, when the delay is too large the code will crash the esp.

Putting the code into a function introduces some non-blocking time and so is in effect "delaying the delay" on each iteration of the loop and as such the code works.

Comment: `delay()` still allows WiFi and TCP/IP tasks to run. Even if it didn't your shorter delay would still be to long and putting `yield()` at the end of `loop()` is useless since it would be run after each end of the loop iteration anyway. [docs](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/reference.md#timing-and-delays)

Comment: @gre_gor - your comment contradicts itself. "Even if it didn't your shorter delay would still be to (sic) long" - how can it be too long if it doesn't block?

Comment: I meant "Even if it didn't allow WiFi and TCP/IP tasks to run (i.e. blocking), your shorter delay would still be too long ".

Comment: Fraser, you're right about the delay; it would typically crash after a delay that happened to be about five seconds or more - so this answer makes sense.
What you're saying is very interesting since it could, and should, affect quite a bit of Arduino coding. Do you have any sources where I could find some light reading on the matter of non-blocking code in separate functions?